# Slim Framework set name for PDF

Tags: php, slim

I do not get pdf name set while downloading the PDF From Slim Framework As I have Assigned the name for pdf Through PDF Set Options

Like This:

```
<?php
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
    $response = $this->response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
    $response->write($pdf->Output('My_cool_PDF.pdf', 'S'));
?>
```

But the file is getting downloaded by assigning name of the route name passed through html.

Example Url : http://localhost:8080/collections/getBranchWisePDF/1

if param is set 1 the filename is 1 which is assigned to pdf and the file gets downloaded

any options to change the pdf name using TCP Pdf and Slim Framework.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which library you're using to handle PDF files, so I can't fully understand the `$pdf->Output('My_cool_PDF.pdf', 'S')` part, but you can try to set file name by sending an additional header with your response:

```
<?php
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
    $response = $this->response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf')
        // Here we appned another header to let the browser know about the file name
        ->withAddedHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=My_cool_PDF.pdf');
    $response->write($pdf->Output('My_cool_PDF.pdf', 'S'));
?>
```

Comment: it will work if you tcpdf with slim framework for request